# Xcode debugging: how to view xmm registers in readable form

Tags: xcode, debugging, sse

I'm attempting to debug some code (in assembly view), and all I see are character arrays when I expand the xmm registers.  Is there a way to view them in a more user-friendly way?

Thanks to the answer below, I came up with the following so as to not go crazy:

```
expr (void)printf("xmm0: %f\n xmm1: %f\n xmm2: %f\n xmm3: %f\n xmm4: %f\n xmm5: %f\n xmm6: %f\n xmm7: %f\n xmm8: %f\n",$xmm0, $xmm1, $xmm2, $xmm3, $xmm4, $xmm5, $xmm6, $xmm7, $xmm8)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think part of the problem was running the iOS simulator as 32-bit rather than 64-bit.  If I right click on expressions, "Add Expression", I can do this:

> (double&)$xmm0

You may also right click on the register and place this in summary format:

> {(double&)$VAR}

Comment: Could you elaborate why it needs to be a reference?

Answer (score 4):

Using LLDB (while in the Xcode console), you can use:

```
expr (void)printf("%f\n",$xmm0)
```

(or any other XMM register...

[image]

Comment: @xtravar It will print the value of the XMM0 register as a double... If it's "not what you expect", maybe you have another issue... Hard to tell without more details...

Comment: Your method prints: 0.000000

The debugger shows: {
  [0] = 'o'
  [1] = '\x12'
  [2] = '\x83'
  [3] = ':'
  [4] = '\0'
  [5] = '\0'
  [6] = '\0'
  [7] = '\0'
  [8] = '\0'
  [9] = '\0'
  [10] = '\0'
  [11] = '\0'
  [12] = '\0'
  [13] = '\0'
  [14] = '\0'
  [15] = '\0'
}

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are saying... See the screenshot I just added...

Comment: The reason your solution did not work was because I was using the 32-bit iOS simulator rather than the 64-bit.  It works now.  It is a shame Xcode doesn't automatically just work, though.

Comment: Using lldb you can run something like: 'register read xmm0', much more friendly imo